# What is the technical name of the conical totem lanterns scattered in the Tuanul village field?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens

I am building a Tuanul raid diorama based on the opening scene of *Star Wars: The Force Awakens* (2015).

[image: Screenshot from Star Wars: The Force Awakens (2015), showing the raid on Jakku; a conical lamp in the foreground is marked with a yellow circle].

I have built some conical totem lanterns like the one marked in the picture. I need to know (if possible) the name of those devices. Does anyone know the technical name of those devices?

---

So far, the closest device that I have found with a resemblance to the cones is a vaporator depicted at Watto's Junkshop on page 20 of the DK Star Wars Complete Locations (Episode I The Phantom Menace). The main difference is obviously the size.

[image: External view of Watto's Junkshop]

Comment: "Tuanul is little more than a few wattle-and-daub huts clustered around a large vaporator cistern." My best guess is that they're something to do with the vaporator cistern...

Comment: I've looked in the Visual Dictionary and all three novelisations that mention the village. No mention of these cone things

Answer (score 10):

Upon recommendation of @Valorum, after asking [Jake Lunt Davies](https://jakelunt.com/), creature and droid Concept Designer on *Star Wars: The Force Awakens* (including BB-8), about the conical device, he managed to ask it to the film's Production Designer and they responded thusly:

> *I managed to ask the Production Designer, but I'm afraid to say I don't really have a good answer for you. They generally just add various bits of tech to the sets to give it that Star Wars feel - without necessarily working out their functions.*

It would appear that the conical device doesn't have a name or meaningful function in-universe.

[image: Email screenshot]